# Why is this simple loop in R so slow?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm a beginner with R and I have written this simple loop:

```
for(i in 1:12000){
    if(v$piano.tariff[i] == 2) {v$piano.tariff[i] = 0}
    else {v$piano.tariff[i] = 1}
}
```

Where v is a data frame and piano.tariff one of its columns. What the loop does is simply change each value of the piano.tariff column to either 1 or 0, from their initiali values of 2 and 5.

Now, the code works, but the problem is that it is ridiculously slow. It takes up to **4-5 minutes**  to complete! In C++ o C# such a loop would barely require a few seconds.

Why is this so slow? Is there a faster way to implement this? Or is it simply that R is slow, and that's it?

Comment: If you're newer to R a lot of these questions regarding loops and vectorization are answered in: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could try a vectorized approach here.

*EDIT*
Thanks to Henrik, the previous version was a bit off. I think the new approach is OK.

```
twos <- v$piano.tariff == 2
notwos <- v$piano.tariff != 2
v[twos, "piano.tariff"] <- 0
v[notwos, "piano.tariff"] <- 1
```

Fast enough for you? :)

Comment: It's instantaneous, thanks!! Tho I modified it slightly, since I knew the other value was 5 I used a "==" in the second line, otherwise as Henrik points out, it wouldn't work properly.

Comment: @Master_T see my edit. Henrik noted that my first approach was wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use `ifelse` instead which is a vectorized R function, it'll be faster

```
ifelse(v$piano.tariff==2, 0, 1)
```

Since you didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I couldn't benchmark the performace.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to be careful about loops in R, but more particularly assignments inside loops like `v$piano.tariff[i] = v$piano.tariff[i]+1` which cause the entire vector to be re-allocated.

Refer to Patrick Burns online book on these sorts of issues [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for a lot more detail on this.